MongoServerSelectionError with NextAuth when not on local network
Whenever I'm working on a project using NextAuth away from home, auth stops working due to a MongoServerSelectionError. I'm home from school right now and I've been getting this error despite giving network access to my IP. I've put below my mongo client setup and NextAuth setup. I've just started using NextAuth, so hopefully it's a simple fix, but I haven't been able to find anything. AI told me it was something with SSL, but I'm completely lost.
lib/mongodb.ts
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

if (!process.env.MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error('Invalid/Missing environment variable: "MONGODB_URI"');
}

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const options = {};

let client;
let clientPromise: Promise<MongoClient>;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
  const globalWithMongo = global as typeof globalThis & {
    _mongoClientPromise?: Promise<MongoClient>;
  };

  if (!globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }
  clientPromise = globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}

export default clientPromise;

api/auth/[...nextAuth]
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter";
import clientPromise from "@/app/lib/mongodb";

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise, {
    databaseName: "db1",
    collections: {
      Users: "users",
    },
  }),
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile }) {
      return true;
    },
    async session({ session, user }) {
      return session;
    },
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

error
[next-auth][error][adapter_error_getUserByAccount] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#adapter_error_getuserbyaccount 40B81BEE01000000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1590:SSL alert number 80
 {
  message: '40B81BEE01000000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1590:SSL alert number 80\n',
  stack: 'MongoServerSelectionError: 40B81BEE01000000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1590:SSL alert number 80\n' +
    '\n' +
    '    at Topology.selectServer (/Users/garrett/Documents/[03] Code/reformify/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:303:38)\n' +
    '    at async Topology._connect (/Users/garrett/Documents/[03] Code/reformify/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:196:28)\n' +
    '    at async Topology.connect (/Users/garrett/Documents/[03] Code/reformify/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:158:13)\n' +
    '    at async topologyConnect (/Users/garrett/Documents/[03] Code/reformify/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:223:17)\n' +
    '    at async MongoClient._connect (/Users/garrett/Documents/[03] Code/reformify/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:236:13)\n' +
    '    at async MongoClient.connect (/Users/garrett/Documents/[03] Code/reformify/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:161:13)',
  name: 'MongoServerSelectionError'
}
[next-auth][error][OAUTH_CALLBACK_HANDLER_ERROR] 
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#oauth_callback_handler_error 40B81BEE01000000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1590:SSL alert number 80
 Error [GetUserByAccountError]: 40B81BEE01000000:error:0A000438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1590:SSL alert number 80

    at Topology.selectServer (node_modules/mongodb/src/sdam/topology.ts:610:29)
    at async Topology._connect (node_modules/mongodb/src/sdam/topology.ts:463:21)
    at async Topology.connect (node_modules/mongodb/src/sdam/topology.ts:410:6)
    at async topologyConnect (node_modules/mongodb/src/mongo_client.ts:596:8)
    at async MongoClient._connect (node_modules/mongodb/src/mongo_client.ts:608:6)
    at async MongoClient.connect (node_modules/mongodb/src/mongo_client.ts:520:6) {
  code: undefined
}


Wow, fixed 5 minutes later. It's something to do with MongoDB permissions. Since we're in development it's not a big deal, so I just allowed all IPs and it worked. Odd because I allowed my current IP and it didn't work, but that's a temporary fix.
